# If value in column I is 2 or 3, the copy corresponding B:D in same row and paste on cover page

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet that can be updated. The user inputs a sheet number to real time update and then macro will look at `Column 9 (I)` and copy `B:D` of that row and paste it in cells on the front sheet (coverpage). This will continue until all data in the data sheet has run through.

```
Sub Update_Current()
    Dim Page
    Dim lastrow As Long, i As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    lastrow = ActiveSheet.Range("D1000").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    Page = InputBox("Which week would you like to update?")

    If Page = 1 Then
        Worksheets("Week(1)").Select

        For i = 6 To 100
            If ws.Cells(i, 9) = "2" Or ws.Cells(i, 9) = "3" Then
                Range("i,2:1,4").Copy

                {TORN ON WHAT GOES HERE}

            End If
        Next i
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `1` What do you mean by PAGE? `2` Your question title says A:C but question says B:D Which is it?

Comment: {TORN ON WHAT GOES HERE} what is there ? Can u paste them.

Comment: @Santosh: I guess he is asking as to what should go there :)

Comment: Yes, I don't have anything concrete,it is fair game. And I apoligzie, it is B:D. I messed that one up. :p

Comment: And a page, I mean the first worksheet. I want to go to a certain sheet, all of which are the same templete just different data from each week. Then depedning on the data, pulling certain data to the first worksheet to disply work in progress and completed work (the 2 and the 3).

Answer (score 0):

I know it is late but cannot leave a question without an answer when i think i have one. Hopefully this will help someone else.

```
Sub Update_Current()
Dim Page
Dim lastrow As Long, i As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

Page = InputBox("Which week would you like to update?")

If Page = 1 Then
   Set ws = Worksheets("Week(1)")
   ws.Select
    For i = 2 To 100
        If ws.Cells(i, 9) = "2" Or ws.Cells(i, 9) = "3" Then
            ws.Range("B" & i & ":D" & i).Copy
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CoverPage").Select
            lastrow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CoverPage").Range("D1000").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CoverPage").Range("B" & lastrow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
    Next i
End If
End Sub
```